# Side navigation to move with scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I want to make the side navigation menu to be in the most left center part of the page and when i scroll down i want it to move as well ( still in the most left center part ).

[This is my code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LQzRQG)

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">Homescreen</a>
      <a href="#">Menu</a>
      <a href="#">Doggos</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
      <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Map</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you add another library, such as [Sticky js](http://stickyjs.com/) ?

Comment: I will try this out, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I hope this will help you: (This is pure HTML/CSS):
*Run the snippet and see the reusult:*

```css
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        #main {
            width: 70%;
            min-height: 1000px;
            float: right;
            background-color: darkblue;
        }
        #sidebar-container {
            height: 100vh;
            float: left;
            width: 30%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        } #sidebar {
            width: 30%;
            background-color: darkgreen;
            min-height: 100px;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="main">

    </div>
    <div id="sidebar-container">
        <div id="sidebar">

        </div>
    </div>
```